# Validate request body not equal to a pattern

Tags: java, spring, micronaut

When validating my request parameters I'm doing a NonNull check but now I want to block certain type of patterns.

```
@Prototype
public class MyObj {
    @NotBlank(message="Error: id cannot be null")
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
}
```

Now I have have to block the request that has id matching any of the following patterns

`(\*\s+(\w+)\s+\*)`

`((\w+)\:(\d+)\/(\d+))`

I know I can include a `@Pattern(regexp =`  to allow a specific pattern but not sure how to block a specific pattern. and also to do multiple pattern validations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in the @Pattern annotation to exclude both specified patterns.

```
^(?!(\*\s+(\w+)\s+\*)$)(?!((\w+)\:(\d+)\/(\d+))$).*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still plan to do it via annotation you could create your own.
Using micronaut here a sample:

```java
@Prototype
public class MyObj {
    @NotAllowedPattern(values={onePattern, secondPattern})
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
}



@Singleton
ConstraintValidator<NotAllowedPattern, String> notAllowedPattern() {
   return (value, annotationMetadata, context) -> {
  
      // patterns should be mandatory as per annotation
      Optional<String[]> annotationPatterns = annotationMetadata.stringValue("values");
      String[] patterns = annotationPatterns.get();

      // if a single pattern from the not allowed matches this should return false 
      // and raise a <code>ConstraintViolationException</code> which results into error message.
      return doesNotMatchAllPatterns(value, patterns);
   };
}
```